# Loop Through Current Woocommerce Product Categories Sub Categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to loop through the current category's sub-categories but I'm getting a list of all sub-categories across the whole site including ones in other categories.

Here is my code:

```
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) { 

           echo $sub_category->name ;

            }   
        }
    }       
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: with 'current' do you refer to a taxonomy archive page, or to a single product?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fetch root level categories and then fetch their children in sub query.
Your query will list only terms which is not expected output.

First get parent terms and then fetch their children and process them separately.

Simply use built in wordpress function get_terms() by passing taxonomy as product_cat and parent as your desired product category id. This will return sub categories of given parent product category.

There are functions like get_the_term_list(), the_terms() to help you out formatting such terms.

For more than one depth you csn define functions and go recursively.